# Printer Zebra, any idea why the DNS isn’t updated?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a bunch of Zebra label printers on our (global) network.
I have print-server located at one site that print to all of the Zebras.
The issue is, the printers are having there IP assigned by DHCP and gets there host name registered in the DNS.
If the printer hasn’t been restarted before the DHCP lease is running out the printer or DHCP will not renew the DNS registration: result is that the  print-server can’t see the printer by its host name anymore.
Any idea why the DNS isn’t updated??

Comment: Not without logs or packet capture. Have you run a packet sniffer to see if the printers are even trying to renew their lease?

Answer (score 2):

The lease will only expire if the printers don't behave properly because otherwise they would periodically renew the lease and you wouldn't have this problem. It's normal for the DHCP server to notify the DNS server to delete the entry once the lease has expired, which is what is happening in your case.

You have a number of options.

- Configure DHCP to not delete DNS entries - this really isn't a good idea.
- Configure DHCP reservations and static DNS entries - better but still not great.
- Configure static IP addresses on the printers and static DNS entries - the best and most trouble free option.